# Meteor immediately fails every time - TypeError on any command

Tags: meteor

I have never used meteor before. I'm trying to follow the basic tutorial at https://www.meteor.com/install and running into problems immediately.

`curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` ran fine, but trying to do ANYTHING with meteor (Eg `meteor create foobar`, `meteor help`..) results in the following

```
/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:463
Fiber(function () {
^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:463:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

I have tried on three different machines, and the above problem occurs on two of them.

- meteor FAILS this way on machine #1 (Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS)

  - node v0.10.26
  - npm 1.4.3
- meteor FAILS this way on machine #2 (Ubuntu Server 14.10 virtual machine, freshly upgraded from 14.04.1)

  - node v0.10.35
  - npm 1.4.28
- meteor WORKS FLAWLESSLY on machine #3 (Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS)

  - node v0.10.35
  - npm 1.4.28

I've seen https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1804 and it doesn't appear to be helpful.
I'm at a loss as to where to go from here.

Comment: Meteor comes with node, you can take that out of the equation. Are any of these 64-bit ubuntu?

Comment: Right, good to know. Yes, these are all 64-bit Ubuntu.